# jQuery 'focus' event doesn't work for dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery, input, label, dynamically-generated, onfocus

I generate dynamically

```
<input type="text" id="foo">
<label for="foo">
```

And set listener to *input*:

```
updateWithLabelInputs($("#foo"));
```

And function:

```
function updateWithLabelInputs(withLabel) {
    withLabel.die("focus").live("focus", function (e) {
        $(this).parent().find('label').hide();
    });
    withLabel.die("blur").live("blur", function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parent().find('label').show();
        }
    });    
}
```

When I click by *label* I expect that the event is fired, but it doesn't. 
Interesting: if the same listener apply to the existing (not dynamically) html - it works. 
What is the problem? Why the listener doesn't work for dynamically elements?

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to see all of your code where you create the element and attach the event to it. I'm thinking you're not doing it in proper sequence:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. **If new HTML is being injected into the
>   page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML
>   is placed into the page.** Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.

Earlier version:
You need https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery to do something like that. Or if you're open to using later version of jQuery, without `die` and `live`, use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to include whole plugin for the small task

Comment: Well, you're using die and live functions that have been deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9. You should use .on instead.

Comment: Let's see more code then. Please show how you create the element and populate myElement variable.

Comment: updateWithLabelInputs($("#foo"));          function updateWithLabelInputs(myElement) {
    myElement.die("focus").live("focus", function (e) {
        $(this).parent().find('label').hide();
    });
    myElement.die("blur").live("blur", function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parent().find('label').show();
        }
    });});

Comment: Sorry, please paste in the question, formatted. Looks OK so far, now show how you call that function. I'm more interested in withLabel parameter value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31121/discussion-between-andrew-and-king-julian)